Unknown Identifier issue in Lean 4
In the below example, there are two theorems t1 and t2.  In theorem t2 you receive an error that states that the variable x is an "unknown identifier" in hypothesis h2.  Theorem t1 successfully type checks despite being almost identical (minus the sorry statements).  Can someone explain why the error is generated in theorem t2 and not in t1?
variable (α : Type) (p q : α → Prop)
variable (r : Prop)

theorem t1 : (∀ x, p x ∨ r) → p x ∨ r :=
  (fun h: (∀ x, p x ∨ r) => 
   have h2: p x ∨ r := h x
   show p x ∨ r from h2)

theorem t2 : (∀ x, p x ∨ r) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∨ r :=
 Iff.intro
  (fun h:(∀ x, p x ∨ r) =>
   have h2 : p x ∨ r := h x
   show (∀ x, p x) ∨ r from sorry)
  (sorry)


<div class="rant">
You are a victim of the worst ever design decision made in Lean 4, namely that autoImplict is turned on by default. This horrible, horrible idea allows one to introduce variables in definitions and theorems implicitly (but not elsewhere). It is supposed to help people so that they can write
def horribleDesignDecision (p : α → Prop) := p

instead of
def horribleDesignDecision {α : Type} (p : α → Prop) := p

This is supposed to make life peachy and formalization more fun. But in reality it causes headaches.
</div>
In your particular case, x in t1 is an auto-implicit, it got introduced automagically:
#print t1
-- output:
-- theorem t1 : ∀ (α : Type) (p : α → Prop) (r : Prop) {x : α},
--   (∀ (x : α), p x ∨ r) → p x ∨ r :=

But when you use x in the middle of t2, you are outside of the auto-implicit territory, so you have to put it in by hand:
theorem t2 {x : α}: (∀ x, p x ∨ r) ↔ (∀ x, p x) ∨ r :=
 Iff.intro
  (fun (h: ∀ x, p x ∨ r) =>
   have h2 : p x ∨ r := h x
   show (∀ x, p x) ∨ r from sorry)
  (sorry)

Except, you should not try to work this way. The sane solution is to always put
set_option autoImplicit false

at the top of your file, or even better, set it globally by putting
⟨`autoImplicit, false⟩

in the leanOptions field of your package description in lakefile.lean. The fact that mathlib does it tells us everything we need to know.

I agree the confusion partly comes from auto implicits in t1, but I’m not sure the OP really wants to prove your version of t2.  Instead, they need to think more about how they want their proof to go.

Yes, of course, I just didn't want to change too many things at once.

So the reason your first one works is confusing to you and other newcomers because Lean has the feature foot-gun which has Lean fill in any unspecified variables in the theorem statement automatically (which is the case with the x in t1).
Now for the second, all instances of x in both directions are bound.  There is no reason for adding x to the theorem statement for t2 (despite Andrej’s answer).
Instead, think more carefully about how you want the proof to go.  In the forward direction of the iff, are you trying to prove ∀ x, p x or r.  You have to figure out which one holds.  Your lemma h2 is currently just picking some x out of thin air which is why it is not working, but if you are proving ∀ x, p x you need this to hold for all x (or otherwise you can show r is true instead.) (Note, it is a bit tricky and you need classical reasoning.  Think about it with pen and paper first.  I'm intentionally being vague about the proof.)
If and when you want to show ∀ x, p x in the forward direction and when you want to prove the ∀ x, (p x ∨ r) in the reverse direction, you need to “assume” some arbitrary x. You can do that with fun x : \alpha => .... similar to how you used fun h => to assume the first half of the implication in your proofs above.
See the quantifier chapter of Theorem Proving in Lean for more details.
